# Making a table on android via android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I'm trying to make a table in android studio using a drawable resource as the boarder. I've tried several times and I keep getting an empty screen once I run the emulator.
This is what I see when I launch the app - [AVD Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igYVV.png)

Anyone knows what can I do to fix it ?
Thanks a bunch in advance!

this is my layout file - "content_main" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tabla_cabecera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></TableRow>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabla_cuerpo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView12"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"></TextView>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my drawable resource file - "cell_shape" :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape= "rectangle"  >
    <solid android:color="#010037" />
    <stroke android:width="1dp"  android:color="#ff9"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty app"? Can you post a screen shot?

Comment: I suggest using Android Device Monitor to load the view hierarchy to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: By empty app I mean empty screen, I'll fix that

Comment: I'm still not sure what an "empty screen" is. Please post a screen shot. A picture is worth a thousand words.

Comment: I added a screenshot sorry if I'm not clear

Comment: Please follow my suggestion above.